# Ruby daemons - what is a monitor and how does it work?

Tags: ruby, monitor, daemons

So Ruby's daemons gem lets you set `monitor=true` when you start up your process. What the heck is a monitor and what do you do with it? All you do is specify `true` or `false`...is that creating a log file somewhere? Something that is actually monitoring the process, like `god`? Why is the documentation on what this thing is so horrible?

Or is this actually a Unix thing that everyone is supposed to know about? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/classes/Daemons.html#M00004):

> **:monitor**: Monitor the programs and restart crashed instances.

Looks like it sets up a PID file (i.e. a file holding the daemon's process ID) to track the daemon; if the daemon crashes for some reason, the monitor will restart it.

You'll have to ask the authors why their documentation is so sparse; the source code looks clear enough to the gist of what's going on though. I'd think that anyone that has built a daemon or two would be familiar with the concept of monitoring and restarting them.

Comment: Ahh, so it looks like it has some secondary process that is running constantly and checking that the PID still exists. If not, it (the secondary process) starts daemons back up. Thanks!

Comment: @Rob Cameron: Yeah, pretty much. This sort of thing thing is fairly common for background tasks, OSX's launchd (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) has similar "monitor and restart" logic.